# vue-echarts - How to change cursor type on highlighted space behind bar in bar chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

How to do I change the cursor type to a pointer when I'm hovering over the highlighted space behind a bar in a bar chart?

When hovering over a bar, the cursor is a pointer, but in the space behind the bar it's default. Since I've made the entire bar clickable, I would also like to make the cursor a pointer here. Below is a photo showing where in particular the cursor should be a pointer.

[image: Area of concern for pointer change]

Here is how I define my chart within Vue

```js
    <chart :options="chartOptionsBar"
           theme="infographic"
           @zr:click="selectBar"
           :autoresize="true"
           ref="chart">
    </chart>
```

Thanks for the help!